# Terraform : Beanstalk connection with RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have an error when I build my **Beanstalk environment** thanks to **Terraform**. I use Beanstalk with **Docker**. The error come from the build of Docker Image like we could see thanks to `terraform apply` error :

```
 Error: creating Elastic Beanstalk Environment (app-dev): waiting for completion: 3 errors occurred:
│       * 2023-02-19 18:36:21.159 +0000 UTC (e-jnwgwcdy7q) : Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
│       * 2023-02-19 18:36:21.159 +0000 UTC (e-jnwgwcdy7q) : Instance deployment failed to build the Docker image. The deployment failed.
│       * 2023-02-19 18:36:24.538 +0000 UTC (e-jnwgwcdy7q) : [Instance: i-0feeb08c4da8ff1b5] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
```

The *custom Docker image* contains a **Django Rest API** where I install my requirements and where I also made migrations inside my RDS instance. The DRF API gets the connection endpoints thanks to environment variables.

Inside it, I provide this **Beanstalk** stack with **application, environment, and application version** :

```py
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "beanstalk_app" {
  name        = var.project_ref
  description = "Beanstalk application for Django App"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "beanstalk_env" {
  name                = var.project_ref
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.beanstalk_app.name
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.5.4 running Docker"
  tier                = "WebServer"
  version_label       = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version.beanstalk_app_version.id
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name = "IamInstanceProfile"
    value = aws_iam_instance_profile.ec2_eb_profile.name
  }

  # Env vars
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_PORT"
    value     = var.project_port
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_NAME"
    value     = var.project_name
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_USER"
    value     = var.project_db_user
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_PASSWORD"
    value     = var.project_db_pwd
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DJANDO_ADMIN_PWD"
    value     = var.project_admin_pwd
  }

  # Logs
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs"
    name      = "StreamLogs"
    value     = "true"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs"
    name      = "RetentionInDays"
    value     = "1"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs"
    name      = "DeleteOnTerminate"
    value     = "false"
  }

  # Logs health
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs:health"
    name      = "HealthStreamingEnabled"
    value     = "true"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs:health"
    name      = "DeleteOnTerminate"
    value     = "true"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs:health"
    name      = "RetentionInDays"
    value     = "1"
  }

  # Tags
  tags = {
    Name = var.project_ref
    Environment = var.project_env
  }
}
  
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "beanstalk_app_version" {
  name        = var.project_ref
  description = "application version created by terraform"
  application = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.beanstalk_app.id
  bucket      = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_back.id
  key         = aws_s3_object.s3_bucket_back_zip.id
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "ec2_eb_profile" {
  name = "beanstalk-service-user"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.ec2_eb_role.name}"
  tags = {
    Name = var.project_ref
    Environment = var.project_env
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ec2_eb_role" {
  name = "beanstalk-service-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.instance_assume_role_policy.json
}
```

I also provide a **RDS instance** like :

```py
resource "aws_db_instance" "db_instance_project" {
  allocated_storage      = 10
  db_name                = var.project_name
  engine                 = "postgres"
  engine_version         = "13.7"
  instance_class         = "db.t3.micro"
  username               = var.project_db_user
  password               = var.project_db_pwd
  skip_final_snapshot    = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_default_security_group.security_group.id]
  publicly_accessible    = true
}
```

The security group called in db_instance was correctly opened on the corresponding port.

The **application version called S3 Bucket** to fetch a `docker-compose.yaml` stack inside a zip archive with the code to launch.

To conclude, I wonder if there is a way ton **debug the Docker Image build** or the **Terraform launch build** ? My eb-engine.log is empty, and all CloudWatch logs are empty also. Is there another way to read logs ?
Do you think this is an error to contact RDS instance ? I purposely opened the RDS public for testing, but there was no change after.

Thanks for your answer and ideas.

***EDIT 20/02/2023*** : I also tried to insert **database config** inside my Beanstalk environment like :

```
setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "HasCoupleDatabase"
    value     = false
}
setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBEngine"
    value     = "postgres"
}
setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBEngineVersion"
    value     = "13.7"
}
setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBInstanceClass"
    value     = "db.t3.micro"
}
setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBUser"
    value     = var.project_db_user
}
setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBPassword"
    value     = var.project_db_pwd
}
```

However, we **couldn't defined a DB_NAME** with this method. So I tried to created an RDS Instance resource to create my DB. Then, I **couldn't insert an RDS_DB_HOST** to my Beanstalk settings so I don't understand how I can proceed to connect them together.

Comment: SSH to the eb instance of and chech /var/logs

Comment: Can you try with `RDS_HOSTNAME`, `RDS_PORT`, `RDS_DB_NAME`, `RDS_USERNAME` and `RDS_PASSWORD` instead of the `DB_*`?

Comment: @Marcin I had thought about it but I don't see how I can insert an SSH key into my EC2 instances generated by Terraform Beanstalk resource. 

I doesn't see any config in beanstalk environment resources (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elastic_beanstalk_environment#option-settings) and nothing in resources settings (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html)

Do you think I must be write EC2 resources and connect it with a way to my Beanstalk resource ?

Comment: @MarkoE I just inserted an EDIT to my post at the end. I have explained why I doesn't use the Beanstalk settings for RDS instance like the documentation recommend (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html)

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused. You want the RDS instance to be coupled to the Beanstalk environment or not?

Comment: @MarkoE it sounds like he just wants RDS to be *accessible* from the Beanstalk environment, but managed by Terraform, not Elastic Beanstalk. I would call that the "correct" method of using RDS and Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Those environment variables need to be named whatever names your Django app is expecting them to be. Whatever you have configured in your Django configuration file for reading environment variables, that is the name you should give those environment variables in Elastic Beanstalk. You shouldn't be guessing at what names to use for those variables.

Comment: You absolutely need to figure out how to look at your logs to see what the actual error is. It could simply be a DB migration error or something. To specify the SSH key for Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instances, you would specify a configuration value of `EC2KeyName` in the `aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration` namespace. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html  Note that after you specify that setting, it is not applied to any currently running ECS instances, only new instances created after the setting was specified.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The `EC2KeyName` attribute in `aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration` setting allowed me to connect on Beanstalk EC2 instance. I could read my log and detect an error concerning CloudWatch logs permissions in Beanstalk Policies. 
This error was fixed. Thanks !